# Mongoose Warn Util Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
    init: () => {
        const dbOptions = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            autoIndex: false,
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            reconnectInterval: 500,
            poolSize: 5,
            connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
            family:4
        };

        mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:secret@chika.xbf6o.mongodb.net/guilds?retryWrites=true&w=majority', dbOptions);
        mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

        mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
            console.log('Mongoose bağlantısı başarılı!');
        });

        mongoose.connection.on('err', err => {
            console.error(`Mongoose bağlantı hatası: \n${err.stack}`);
        });

        mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
            console.warn('Mongoose bağlantısı kayboldu');
});
}}
```

this is my mongoose util command but i get this warn what should i do

(node:18476) DeprecationWarning: The option 'reconnectTries' is incompatible with the unified topology, please read more by visiting http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/

(node:18476) DeprecationWarning: The option 'reconnectInterval' is incompatible with the unified topology, please read more by visiting http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options) you can see that there are options (like autoReconnect, connectTimeoutMS, reconnectTries, reconnectInterval, etc.) that are only important if you're running without the unified topology.

> reconnectTries - If you're connected to a single server or mongos proxy (as opposed to a replica set), the MongoDB driver will try to reconnect every reconnectInterval milliseconds for reconnectTries times, and give up afterward. When the driver gives up, the mongoose connection emits a reconnectFailed event. This option does nothing for replica set connections.

You can update your `dbOptions` object by removing these deprecated options.

Comment: :) I'm trying now